# Self Organizing maps(SOM) not effective in clustering images in the color space?

Tags: neural-network, color-space, knn, self-organizing-maps

I am trying to reproduce the experiments on the ai-junkie website http://www.ai-junkie.com/ann/som/som1.html to cluster/group different colors together using Self Organizing maps(SOM) on a larger color dataset. I use about 400 images of differing solid colors and since they are solid colors, the color values in any color space(for example, RGB) would be same for all the points in a particular image. Hence the features I use before clustering using SOM are just the 3 dimensional color value for each image.

When I perform SOM, source code of which is obtained from http://knnl.sourceforge.net/ with 40 rows , 40 columns and 20 iterations(epoch=20), the result of clustering makes no sense to me. I looks like follows:
[image]

I feel like this is just random clustering(if I can call it that) and even a k-means algorithm would give better results. Any thoughts on what could have possibly gone wrong?

Answer (score 3):

20 iterations is not enough for SOM algorithm. Try rows*columns*500. It's default value for the learning algorithm. On simple datasets like yours you can reduce this number but 20 is too small number. And be patien it's gonna take a while :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks wrong, as you say it looks just like a random clustering.

A variety of things could have gone wrong. A few that come to mind: the number of iterations is not sufficient, the neighborhood function is not adequate, the implementation of the library you're using has some bug.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the example posted on ai-junkie.com directly:

[ai-junkie.com SOM Demo](http://www.ai-junkie.com/files/SOMDemo.zip)

Not sure what the SourceForge library is. Or are you asking for help debugging it?

Answer (score 0):

i have made a similar SOM with AForge, you can have the source if still need. i tried with a 4*4 and a 16*16 SOM, and i just needed a few iterations (<100) to adap. Sure, it also depends on the learning factor.